# struts json plugin how to avoid property name being added to json

Tags: java, json, struts2

I have a struts action like so....

```
    <action name="sohWeeklyStatistics" class="com.myer.eposweb.action.StockOnHandHealthAction" method="weeklyStatistics">
        <result name="success" type="json" >
            <param name="includeProperties">weeklyStatistics.*</param>
        </result>       
    </action>
```

It is creating the following json (with the property name)....

```
{"weeklyStatistics":{"data":[[1432598400000,49895],[1432684800000,57440],[1432771200000,67154],[1432857600000,70460],[1432944000000,71602],[1433030400000,63484],[1433116800000,47127]],"label":"Weekly Statistics"}}
```

But really all I want the json without the property name like so ...

```
{"data":[[1432598400000,49895],[1432684800000,57440],[1432771200000,67154],[1432857600000,70460],[1432944000000,71602],[1433030400000,63484],[1433116800000,47127]],"label":"Weekly Statistics"}
```

How can I define my struts json plugin action to not append the property name to the json?

thanks

Comment: `<param name="root">weeklyStatistics</param>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2 jquery sj:select and json result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580207/struts-2-jquery-sjselect-and-json-result)

Comment: Or more directly using the excludeProperties as can be seen here (using annotations, modify accordingly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796390/struts2-json-serialization-of-items